# Using 'cifs' to connect to windows share

Tags: windows, ubuntu, active-directory, share

I am working with UBUNTU 12.04, and am trying to connect to a windows share (SBS2008r2).

If i use the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //domain/share /media/files -o credentials=/home/linux/.smbcredentials
```

my folder gets mounted correctly.

However, when i try to make this mount automatically by adding the following line in the /etc/fstab:

```
//domain/share /media/filescredentials=/home/linux/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

and then run the command:

```
sudo mount -a
```

I get the following error:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by removing the `sec=ntlm` option.

Try adding this to /etc/fstab:

```
//domain/share /media/filescredentials=/home/linux/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```